# First line of ltxtable/longtable indented

Tags: indentation, longtable, ltxtable

I am using the `ltxtable` package to be able to set the `longtable` to `\textwidth`

I have `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}'` in the preamble.

The first line of each `longtable` is indented, how do I get rid of that?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhVWo.png)

```
\subsubsection*{Test}
\label{test}

\begin{filecontents}{longtab.tex}
    \begin{longtable}{p{0.5\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}X}
    \addtocounter{table}{-1}
     one &   & two \\
     three &   & four \\
    \end{longtable}%
\end{filecontents}
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{longtab}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX tries to ignore spaces at the begin of a table cell by using `\ignorespaces`. But the space after `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` caused by the line end is not seen and therefore not ignored by the automatically added `\ignorespaces`. This line end can be commented out:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Test}
\label{test}

\begin{filecontents}{longtab.tex}
    \begin{longtable}{p{0.5\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}X}
    \addtocounter{table}{-1}%
     one &   & two \\
     three &   & four \\
    \end{longtable}%
\end{filecontents}
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{longtab}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If you do not want to have the remaining "indentation" by the horizontal space automatically added around table cells, then this can be suppressed by `@{}` in the table column specification. This makes sense, if there are not horizontal lines in the table:

```
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{0.5\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}X@{}}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: On the other hand, `\addtocounter` probably doesn't belong in the `longtable`.